# AngularJS ngRoute 404 page not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have been trying to figure out why my view doesn't work.  I am not sure if I am missing dependencies or just have something simple wrong.

when I run the program through pycharm is shows the index.html page, and when I click on one of the links to the different views it displays a 404 page not found.

> I have these directories under my project folder:
>
> -lib
>   -css
>   -partials
>   -scripts
>
> -index.html

can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

---

AngularJS js file:

```
  var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);
    mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',
      function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'controller_home'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/about.html',
                controller: 'controller_about'
            })
            .when('/cart', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/cart.html',
                controller: 'controller_cart'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
                controller: 'controller_contact'
            })
            .when('/myAccount', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/myAccount.html',
                controller: 'controller_myAccount'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/partials/home'
            });
    }]);

mainApp.controller('controller_home', ['$scope', function controller_home($scope) {
    $scope.message = "$scope.message : from controller_home";
}])
    .controller('controller_about', ['$scope', function controller_about($scope) {
    $scope.message = "$scope.message : from controller_about";
}])
    .controller('controller_cart', ['$scope', function controller_cart($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'this is the cart';
}]);
```

---

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Webpage Title</title>

    <!--Stylesheet index.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/animations.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mainApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Site Header-->
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Header to Page</h1>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!--Site Navigation Bar-->
    <div>
        <a href="/home">Product</a> |
        <a href="/cart">Cart</a> |
        <a href="/about">About</a> |
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a> |
        <a href="/myAccount">My Account</a><br/>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!--Site Footer-->
    <footer class="footer">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </footer>

    <footer class="footer-disclaimer">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="policy.html">Policy and Agreement</a></li>
            <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: about.html, cart.html, contact.html, home.html, and myAccount.html have simple div's that show some text

Comment: Please put a link to the Plunker...

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/gVftUqYNfd3uwCtPAZaL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing dependency **`ngRoute`**

```
  var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

also your controllers should be ,

```
mainApp.controller('controller_home', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "$scope.message : from controller_home";
}])
mainApp.controller('controller_about', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "$scope.message : from controller_about";
}])
mainApp.controller('controller_cart', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'this is the cart';
}]);
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/tVeMwBbnzlB8EVVIhhN2?p=preview)**

Comment: After I added the ngRoute dependency I still receive the same error. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Thank you very much, I stripped out my code and used your in order to fix the problem.

Comment: Mark as answer if it helped